# node + mongodb: Update last object in nested array

Tags: node.js, mongodb

My mongodb collection looks like this

```
{
   channelId: int,
   channelName: string,
   voteHistory: [
       {
           createdAt: date,
           votes: ['old vote','old vote','old vote']
       },
       {
           createdAt: date,
           votes: ['old vote']
       },
       {
           createdAt: date,
           votes: []
       }
   ]
}
...
```

`voteHistory` is sorted by `createdAt` (date) ascending. If i wanted to push an object to the `votes` array in the LAST (most recent) object in `voteHistory`, how would i do that with one operation?

The result should look like this

```
{
   channelId: int,
   channelName: string,
   voteHistory: [
       {
           createdAt: date,
           votes: ['old vote','old vote','old vote']
       },
       {
           createdAt: date,
           votes: ['old vote']
       },
       {
           createdAt: date,
           votes: ['new vote!!']
       }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Sorry if the post wasn't clear, but this is for mongodb.

Comment: It's clear, but I probably could point you to an existing point or two which basically conclude that it would be far more simple to ensure your "last" array item was in fact always the "first" array item. MongoDB has a `$position` modifier for `$push` which can ensure your arrays are in fact always recorded in this order. Point being you can always `"$push": { "voteHistory.0.votes": "new vote!!" }` but you **cannot** `"$push": { voteHistory.-1.votes": "new vote!!" }` if you catch my drift. So ensure you "prepend" rather than "append".

Comment: @Neil funnily enough i had already decided to give up and do it the way you said. my array is already sorted, so it doesn't matter which direction it's sorted in!

Answer (score 0):

Since $push and $pull can't be part of a singular atomic operation I thing the easiest way is to do it in 2 operations

1/ `findOne()` or even better `findById()`

2/ Modify the array in memory => Save your document

You can maybe do it in one singular operation by combining slice, length and push operator but honestly I'm not sure about efficiency.